# hide view and shows another with the clickof button with extjs

Tags: controller, extjs4, actionview

i have a login view  after i click connect button  i want that the login form desapper and the main view will be shown.
i have a login view after i click connect button i want that the login form desapper and the main view will be shown.
i have a login view after i click connect button i want that the login form desapper and the main view will be shown.
i use this

```
'login button[action=connect]': {  
            'click' : function(button, event, opt) {  
                var view = Ext.widget('home');}// home c'est le main view
```

but when i run this the login view does not desapper  i see the two view on the same page

any one have a solution

Comment: was the answer below helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You have to close the login view:

```
Ext.getCmp('login_view_id').close(); //login_view_id : the 'id' of the login view
```

or

```
this.getLogin().close(); //login : refrence to the login view
```

Comment: ok thanx yes i resolve it i add this line
this.getLogin().close();

Comment: can you give me your email adress

Comment: you're welcome: bensaid.amine88@gmail.com.  
can you put it as resolved plz?

Answer (score 0):

use card layout to shuffle your views in and out: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Card